How to use or disable invalid cookie separators in http request header
In http POST request Python client sends cookies reparated by comma in Cookie: header like
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Host:   example.com
User-Agent: python-requests/2.22.0
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Content-Type:   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: .MyAuth=CfDJKDs7DFPZPOQnd8YtbX, Company=165
Content-Length: 0

ASP.NET 9 MVC application recognizes comma as cookie separator and parses .MyAuth and Company cookies properly.
.MyAuth cookie is logged in Apache access.log file. In apache conf file:
LogFormat "{.MyAuth}C" minulogi
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log minulogi

Using this Apache logs also Company cookie. Apache log file contains:
CfDJKDs7DFPZPOQnd8YtbX, Company=165

How to force Apache to log only .MyAuth cookie value? apache log shoud contain
CfDJKDs7DFPZPOQnd8YtbX

Or how force Apache or ASP.NET 9 MVC application to return http error if cookies with invalid separator are used ?

you could split on comma and a space, or semicolon and a space.  (could be either methinks)  There is a slight security concern with writing tokens to logs though.

How to force Apache to make this splitting to log only .MyAuth cookie?
